# How to Test Phase Difference Between Two Groups of Signals?

Tags: signal-processing

Imagine I have two groups of signals A and B having three samples each.

How can I find out whether there is a statistically significant “phase difference” between groups A and B?

```
A1 = [1 3 -1 2];
A2 = [1 3 -2 3];
A3 = [1 4 -3 4];

B1 = [2 3 -1 5];
B2 = [2 4 -2 6];
B3 = [2 4 -4 5];
```

Comment: What is a “phase difference” here?

Comment: I assume that my signals are periodic and we can see their cycles. For example, one grope may be a pi ahead of another group in total

Comment: I think this was accidentally posted to StackOverflow.com instead to signals.stackexchange.com. But even there, I think it's kind of possible people will ask you to add a lot more background to your question.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27545171/52738) is a good starting point?